# Is the cdf of the folded normal log concave?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance  $\sigma^2$, and let $Y=|X|$.

I would like to prove that the cdf of Y is log-concave on the positive real axis.

I am able to show that the cdf of Y is not *concave* (on the positive real axis). But numerical simulations seem to suggest it is *log-concave*. Many thanks to anyone who can help.

For a definition of the folded normal see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution